# Mongoose multiple where on same field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, where-clause

Using mongoose with express to build a simple API.

I want to select multiple types of the same crop from the database.

```
crops = ["cassava", "hot peppers", "tomato", "cocoa"];

crops.forEach(function(el){
    Q = Crop.where("commodity").regex(new RegExp(el, "i")); 
});

Q.exec(function(err, data){
    if(!err){ 
        console.log(data);
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

However this only brings back the last crop (cocoa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$in` operator for a case like this.  Using Mongoose you can do it as:

```
var crops = [/cassava/i, /hot peppers/i, /tomato/i, /cocoa/i];
var Q = Crop.where("commodity").in(crops);
Q.exec(function(err, docs) {...});
```

Comment: Had to use back the new RegExp(el, "i"), was not possible to change the string to the form highlighted in your solution but can confirm that it works